# Can anybody tell me how the time complexity is O(n*n!) and not o(n^n) for this program?

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

Why is the time complexity is `O(n*n!)` and not `o(n^n)` for this program?

```
 void perm(String str, String prefix){
     if(str.length() == 0){
         System.out.println(prefix);
     } else{
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
           String rem = str.substring(0, i) + 
                           str.substring(i + 1);
           perm(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would remove the `System.out` statement because it changes the result as it is not an atomic command

Answer (score 1):

It is both. We have

```
n! = 1 * 2 * ... * n <= 1 * n * ... * n = n^(n-1)
```

so `n * n! = O(n^n)`. Now for small `o`, things look a bit differently, because we have to proof that for any constant factor `c` exists `n`, such that `c * n * n! < n^n`.

But this isn't that complicated either. Let's pick an arbitrary `c`, then (for `n>=3`):

```
(n * n!)/(n^n) = n!/n^(n-1) = (n-1)!/n^(n-2) = 1/n * 2/n * ... * (n-1)/n < 
< 1/n * ((n-1)/n)^(n-3) <= 1/n
```

So we've got `n * (n * n!) < n^n`. So for our `c`, we can just pick `n >= c` and we're good. Thus also `n * n! = o(n^n)`. So your algorithm is both `O(n * n!)` and `o(n^n)`.

Comment: If we do an analysis the it should be T(n)=nT(n-1)+c right? and according to that it should be O(n^n)

Comment: @AnkurBose you'd have to first transform the recurrence into a non-recursive form before you can do analysis of lower order terms. But generally `f = o(g)` automatically implies `f = O(g)` for arbitrary `f` and `g`.

Comment: can you explain me how to get O(n*n!) the n! part is for the number of permutations and multiplied by n for?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the string gets shorter.

I assume the following program without the `System.out`

```
 void perm(String str, String prefix){
     if(str.length() == 0){
     } else{
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
           String rem = str.substring(0, i) + 
                           str.substring(i + 1);
           perm(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
       }
    }
 }
```

Lets assume the string has zero characters. Than the runtime is the if statement, which is `O(1) = O(c)`.

For a String of length `n` it is abusing notation `O(c1+n*c2*O(n-1))` to illustrate recursion where `c2` is runtime for substring. Hence runtime is `O(n!) = O(n*n!)` which is btw. `O(n^n)` as `O(n!) = O(n^n)`. However, there is probably a difference in small o notation.